# convert web.config to .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite, web-config

Hello: I need help converting my IIS rewrite rules to an .htaccess file.
I'm not very experienced with server rules (I mostly design and develop websites).
I need some assistance. I am currently moving over a website (dolyn.com) from another server to ours and they originally launched it using a WIMP setup therefore used the URL Rewrite from IIS (web.config) rather than the mod_rewrite module from Apache (.htacces) [I really don't quite get the logistics of it - I've just been asked to make sure it works on our server. Here's the original web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

    <!-- Doesn't work on DEV servers, uncomment it on live site -->
    <!-- httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" /-->

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />

                <!--
                This rule will redirect all requests to a single main domain as specified in the 1st condition, except if it's on a baytek dev site.
                Instructions:
                    1. Enable the rule
                    2. Change "^www.maindomain.com$" to real domain, ex. "^www.bayteksystems.com$", in both places.
                -->

                <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true" enabled="false">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.maindomain.com$" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="dev.bayteksystems.com$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.maindomain.com/{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:1}}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="DynamicURLs" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^_cms.*" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?page={R:1}&amp;url_rewrite=true" />
                </rule>

            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've been doing quite a bit research and it looks like I may also need an .htpasswd file? Is this correct? As you can from the web.config the server its coming from is baytechsystems.com and we're moving it to dnsnetworks.ca

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you need an htpasswd file unless you need authentication (which may be the case, but I don't see anything in your web.comfig. So something like this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.dnsnetworks\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !dev\.dnsnetworks\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dnsnetworks.ca/$1 [L,R=301]

# Add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]]

# Convert to lower case
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*[A-Z].*)$ /${tolower:$1} [L,R=301] 

# DynamicURLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_cms
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1&url_rewrite=true [L]
```

The only problem here is the "Convert to lower case" part. The `tolower` function needs to be defined in your server config. Like this:

```
RewriteMap tolower int:tolower
```

Otherwise, that rule will result in an error. If you don't have access to your server/vhost config, then just comment out that rule, as you're not going to be able to enforce lowercase using mod_rewrite.

Comment: It looks like its redirecting to www.dylon.com - What I want is for it to work under web01.dnsnetworks.ca/dolyn (that's where all the files are... index.php) ..

Comment: when I try to load the site….this is what popped into the error logs;

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/app/website/doly/_includes/common.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /app/website/dolyn/index.php on line 13

I think I am missing the php-devel libraries on the server as its trying to use the php-pear extension of PHP.
its not an easy install, as I am running the latest version of PHP, and the development libraries for my system are not available yet…. what do you think @JonLin

Comment: @user3112402 there's lots of various PHP libraries that don't come with a minimal PHP install, LOTS. But you should probably make sure that `/app/website/doly/_includes/common.php` exists

Comment: @user3112402 does apache/whatever user php runs under have read permissions for that file?